# Slow HTML generation with Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, tomcat

I'm a developer with a problem ;) Currently we're close to an end on our project (using Vaadin) however...

we're getting some trouble with displaying simple data in one of our views. (over 500 KB of data to display, and over 15K DOM elements after Vaadin is done with generating it... + lots, and lots and LOTS seconds before it's done).

My task is to find out how i can make this as small and as fast as possible, so my first guess was to use some other layouts than those avaliable in standar Vaadin.

I used WeeLayout, DashLayout and CssLayout(default), compare is below:

```
weeLayout 
- page size:            990 KB
- DOM elements (SMALL): 1454
- DOM elements (BIG):   15423
cssLayout
- page size:            886 KB
- DOM elements (SMALL): 1434
- DOM elements (BIG):   13799
DashLayout 
- page size:            938 KB
- DOM elements (SMALL): 1408 
- DOM elements (BIG):   12163
```

It didn't work. So my other guess is to write my own Layout, can someone help me with this ? I even don't know from what should i start.

Thanks 
Lukasz

Comment: Similar Question, for Vaadin 8: [*Generate an HTML page, and open in a new window, from a Vaadin 8 app*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51691041/642706)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the answer for this is using HTML in CustomLayout.

[Example](http://magi.virtuallypreinstalled.com/book-examples/book/#layout.customlayout.stream)

[And thread where Vaadin devel helped me](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/message/391680)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried LazyLoadingWrapper add-on?

Comment: I'll try that... But, the amount of extra HTML generated by Vaadin is overwhelming. I would rather try to simplyfied it. Do you have any idea how to do so ?

Comment: @Joonas: I think the behaviour of this addon should be a default one in Vaadin. Do you happen to know: in case I have tab UI control, each tab holds a big image, will it prevent browser from fetching the non-visible images? That will save me a lot of traffic.